# nuxt how to manually change axios baseUrl after nuxt build

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

now I have a question, how can I manually change axios baseUrl after build. Just if specified request url changed, I can manually change baseUrl, rather than rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new `axios` instance using `axios.create()` function. You can then use this instance to make calls on the new baseUrl.

```
const myNewInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://my-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 3000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

You can also prototype it to `Vue` object inside a `plugin` and then you can access it from all components and pages.

Comment: I`m not really understand how to manually change baseURL. Can I put baseUrl config into static file.

Comment: You cannot change it after the build. Why would you want to change it in runtime? If you have multiple APIs or endpoints you want to access, you should create a separate axios instance for each one of them.

Comment: Also its currently impossible to change it during runtime. This feature is supposedly coming soon (https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/88).

Comment: Because my project`s actual requset address is depend on actual deployment server`s ip address, So I just want to simply change the static baseUrl,rather than to rebuild.

Comment: Its's not possible. I suggest you to create a config file where you have the baseUrl defined, then import it in `nuxt.config.js` and set it for `axios`. Then create a separated build for every deployment, where you get the config variables from ENV.

Comment: @JackieTsien if you still wanted to know how to set config variables for ENV check out my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the `baseUrl` using an environment variable called `API_URL`. Just set it to whatever URL you need. Please refer to the official documentation here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html#baseurl

Also, in case you want to overwrite the `browserBaseUrl` as well, you can do so the same way, using the `API_URL_BROWSER` environment variable.

Hint: you can set environment variables for a single command by prepending them. So, technically, this should work:

```sh
API_URL="https://example.com" nuxt start
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cross-env: `npm install cross-env`

In your project add a folder named `environment`
and under the folder you could have different `environment` (e.g. development, staging, production)

[image: environment folder]

Your environment configs will have your `baseUrl` and other configs, let's say for development you could have your localhost then for the staging or production you could have your `API_URL`

`defaults.json \\development` 
[image: development config]

`defaults.prod.json \\production`
[image: production config]

In `nuxt.config.ts` build > extend configure your different environment

[image: nuxt.config.ts build extend envi]

This will replace `defaults.json` depending on which environment we will run our script in `package.json`.

In `package.json` configure your script to what environment will be run (e.g `npm run start` will use `NODE_ENV=development` which will use the `defaults.json` with `baseUrl: http://localhost:3000` and `npm run build` will use `defaults.prod.json` with `baseUrl: http://www.API_URL.com` and other configs

[image: package.json cross env config]

For more detail you could see [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Comment: can I change api url after webpack packaging？

Answer (score 0):

You can use [axios-multi-host](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-multi-host), it has built in changing host by calling `host.updateList()`

example:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { AxiosMultiHost } from 'axios-multi-host'

const host = new AxiosMultiHost(['https://google.com'])

const api = axios.create()
api.interceptors.request.use(host.middleware)
```

then change the host

```js
host.updateList(['https://bing.com'])
```